# after android.os.Process.setThreadPriority, myThread.getPriority not working android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

`myThread.getPriority()` is giving me 5 although I set the priority of `myThread` using "android.os.Process.setThreadPriority"  as follows.

```
r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority
        (android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_AUDIO);
        ...
        while (true) {
            ...
        }
    }
};

myThread = new Thread(recordingProcess);
myThread.start();
```

Comment: Where are you testing this?  There's no code to call getPriority here (making sure it isn't a race condition)

Comment: I tried adding mythread.getPriority() just before the while statement inside the definition of the runnable